# Forwarding JavaScript function values to the C#

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I need to pass the values from the JavaScript function in to the C#.

Basically I get the values from the columns in the GridView and need to pass them to the c# with button click.

This is the JavaScript code that takes the values from the two columns:

```
 var myCollection = [];
                       $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                           var row = this;
                           var myObj = {

                               label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
                               opis:valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))
                           };
                           myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;
                       });

                       function valuefromType(control) {
                           var type = $(control).prop('nodeName').toLowerCase();
                           switch (type) {
                               case "input":
                                   return $(control).val();
                                   break;
                               case "span":
                                   return $(control).text();
                                   break;
                               case "select":
                                   return $(control).val();
                                   break;

                           }
                       }
```

The function:

```
function updateArray() {
                 alert('Snimljeno!');
                 var myCollection = [];
                     $('#MainContent_gvKarakteristike tbody').find('tr:gt(0)').each(function () {
                         var row = this;
                         var myObj = {

                             label: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(1)').children())),
                             opis: valuefromType($(row).find($(row).find('td:eq(2)').children()))
                         };
                         myCollection[myCollection.length] = myObj;
                     });
                     $("MainContent_gvKarakteristike_ddlOpis_0").remove();
                 }
```

C# button:

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Save" autopostback="true" OnClientClick="return updateArray()" OnClick="btnButton_Click"  />
```

Result so far on the font end side. The values of the array(myCollection) that takes the values when button is clicked.

```
myCollection
(6) […]
​
0: Object { label: "1", opis: "Value1" }
​
1: Object { label: "2", opis: "Test1" }
​
2: Object { label: "3", opis: "Test2" }
​
3: Object { label: "5", opis: "4" }
​
4: Object { label: "9", opis: "Test4" }
​
5: Object { label: "15", opis: "Test5" }
​
length: 6
```

I need help to pass the value from javascript with taken values to the C# so I can later store them to the database.

```
protected void btnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

}
```

Comment: You shouldn't mix autopostback and server side onclick with javascript on click.

Comment: I see. Can you help me a little with code.
I have a problem. Array myCollection only updates when the page is reloaded. It would me good if it updates on button click.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the values to the backend code using `ajax` call with the help of `WebMethod` attribute.

So your backend code will look like

```
[WebMethod]
public static string StoreGridData(object[] obj)
{
   if (obj.Length == 0) return string.Empty;

   //save values to database

   return "Success";
}
```

Your fontend code will be

```
function updateArray() {
 //do your normal check to get the data for your collection
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Yourpage.aspx/StoreGridData",
    data: {obj: myCollection },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
 });
}
```

Don't forget to add `Using System.Web.Services` reference in your `CS` file. Finally, change your button code to

```
<button id="someButton" onclick="updateArray()" type="button">Save</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I have a problem when I change code to your button. The array update won't work. 
Array  take's all the values from the columns and only updates when page is reloaded. Can you help with this !?

Comment: @freej17 Is the grid populated with data in `Page_Load` event?

Comment: Yes everything is in :

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }